# How to change external script url from node module (webpack?)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

I'm a react noob here, using Electron also.

I just installed the npm package called `react-facebook-login` and when I try to test the facebook login I get a console error:

`GET file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

I understand this is incorrect and it should be https: instead of file: but even if I change the library file in the node_modules directory it does not change.

The error shows on a `webpack:///./~/react-facebook-login/dist/facebook-login.js?` file which I asume that creates on runtime.

Which should be the correct approach to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a error in the package you're using since //whatever.com/some/path gets resolved with file:// instead of http:// or https://

In other words your script gets loaded but has a error due to bad practice inside the lib. So the package author has to fix this.

Edit:

I was so free to make a Pull Request https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login/pull/152

Comment: @po5i the pull request has been merged it should work from now on ;)